# Send email with aggregated alerts using Kafka Streams

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a simple use case: Aggregate alerts over some period of time (1min) and send an email contains all of alerts happened during this period.

So in general, I have no problem to define a window, aggregate alerts by a user and send an email using Kafka Streams. Works like a charm, if alerts are coming on a regular basis. In case there are no more alerts, sending email will never be triggered. And the reason is obvious: Kafka Streams logic is triggered by incoming events. So if there is no new event in the topic - nothing will happen.

Here is a simple use case that show the problematic:

```
Time: 0:00:00
-> Event 1
-> Event 2
-> Event 3
Time: 0:01:00
-> Event 4 (This will trigger email with events 1,2,3)
```

So, if there is no Event 4 - there will never any email sent.

One of my solution would be to write custom processor and define scheduler that will send an email. Ideally I would still do grouping, aggregation using official Kafka API and only sending email using scheduler logic. In this case it seems I need to share kvStore to the processor (java). Unfortunately I didn't find any well documented articles on that use case.

I've also tried to "delegate" everything onto the processor (adding new event into the custom defined store, go over all event, send an email and remove sent event from the store), but doesn't look "to clean" for me.

```
    var kvStore: KeyValueStore<Window, AlertNotificationMessage>? = null

    override fun init(context: ProcessorContext) {
        kvStore = context.getStateStore(AlertMessageProcessorSupplier.STORE_NAME)
            as KeyValueStore<Window, AlertNotificationMessage>
        context.schedule(
            Duration.ofSeconds(AlertProcessor.AGGREGATION_SECONDS),
            PunctuationType.WALL_CLOCK_TIME,
            this::sendNotification
        )
    }

    override fun process(key: Windowed<String>, value: AlertNotificationMessage) {
        kvStore?.put(
            Window(key.key(), key.window().start(), key.window().end()),
            value
        )
    }

    private fun sendNotification(callTime: Long) {
        kvStore?.all()?.forEach {
            if (it.key.endMs < callTime) {
                notificationService.send(it.key.recipientId, it.value)
                kvStore?.delete(it.key)
            }
        }
    }
```

Did anyone had similar use case and any good solution that also works in multi-partition/fail-over environment?

Answer (score 0):

I have similar use case. Here is the solution:

1. Create a simple producer app to produce fake alerts in each partition at first second of each minute.

   Now the alerts streaming:

   Time: 0:00:00

   -> Fake Events (partition 0~N)

   -> Event 1

   -> Event 2

   -> Event 3

   Time: 0:01:00

   -> Fake Events (partition 0~N)

   -> Event 4 (This will trigger email with events 1,2,3)

   Time: 0:02:00

   -> Fake Events (partition 0~N)
2. In kafka stream app, ignore the fake events when aggregating window